# Add Custom Button for FB Send

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I just had found out that FB.api showing an error that **'This dialog is not available on this device'**. I also do some research about and the answer almost it was almost 3 years ago. For now my question, is there a new update for that I can able to create my own custom fb send button? that when I click on it, it will display a new window or popup. just like whatsapp share button, and line app. thanks in advanced, I want to learn more about this FB API.

as for now i'm using the FB api, try this if it's show something also

```
<div id="send" class="messenger-share">
    <i class="fa fa-messenger"></i>
</div>

<script>
    $("#send").click(function() {
        FB.ui({
            app_id: '665679653572224',
            method: 'send',
            link: "<?php the_permalink(); ?>",
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle to do this, you can see it here.

https://jsfiddle.net/jimedelstein/14mv8kms/2/

All you need to do is replace the URL (I commented it pretty explicitly).

You want to dynamically load the latest facebook api like so

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '665679653572224',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.5'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Since you posted your appId, I updated the init script to use it.

Then, connect the FB.ui "share" call like so:

```
$("#send").click(function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: "<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
  }, function(response) {});
});
```

For more information, I suggest you checkout the documentation that Facebook provides here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript

Comment: Thanks :) that give's me an idea.